# Blogger API suddenly giving Insufficient Permission error

Tags: google-api, blogger

I've been publishing posts to Blogger blogs for a while now with the v3 API.  Suddenly, this morning I'm getting `403 "Insufficient Permission"` errors when I try to insert posts.  To make sure it wasn't something in my code, I tried inserting a post with the [API Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#s/blogger/v3/blogger.posts.insert).  I authorized the request with the provided scope (`https://www.googleapis.com/auth/blogger`) and tried to insert the following post resource:

```
{
  "kind": "blogger#post",
  "blog": {
    "id": "xxxxxxxx"
  },
  "title": "Test Post",
  "content": "This is a test post"
}
```

And when I tried to execute the request, I got the following error:

```
403 Forbidden

- Hide headers -

cache-control:  private, max-age=0
content-encoding:  gzip
content-length:  136
content-type:  application/json; charset=UTF-8
date:  Wed, 11 Sep 2013 18:18:21 GMT
expires:  Wed, 11 Sep 2013 18:18:21 GMT
server:  GSE
www-authenticate:  Bearer realm="https://www.google.com/accounts/AuthSubRequest", error=insufficient_scope, scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/blogger"

{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
  "domain": "global",
  "reason": "insufficientPermissions",
  "message": "Insufficient Permission"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Insufficient Permission"
 }
}
```

Anyone know why this is suddenly not working today?  Thanks!

Comment: Looks like this issue is being talked about on Google's forums and they have people looking into it. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/bloggerdev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this was a Blogger issue.  The problem has been resolved on their side and my app works fine again.

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem as well, to be honest I am glad that I am not the only one having this problem! This error also occurs if you try to do things via the Oauth playground, for me it was getting a list of the users blogs.